# page curl animation of Webview in android

Tags: android-animation

I have webview Which load the html content from the database.I want to page curl effect of the webview .How To Do it..

Thanks

Comment: have you got solution for this? if you got solution please post it..i too need solution for this..

Comment: No I could not get solution for this webview because android does nt allow this

Comment: Is there any alternate solution for this?? other reader like FBReader, Cool Reader are doing pagecurl effect then how they are doing those effect?Is they didnt load html content in webview?

Comment: With the help of html5 and javascript we can do this....

Comment: Do you have any sample code or reference to refer since i didnt work with html5.pls help me its urgent..

Comment: http://netoopsblog.blogspot.in/2012/03/pagepeel-jquery-effect-blogger.html do this

Comment: how can i add those jquery in the webview???

Comment: simple run jquery in browser and get that html file in assest folder run that file in webview...